# Magento 2. Is there a way to disable a Website or Store in the databases?

Tags: magento2, multistore

Would this be possible by means of sql queries?

Answer (score 4):

The store table has a column `is_active`.
Set that to 0 and the store view is disabled.
It does not work for websites. But you can simply disable all store views from that website and you are safe.

```
`UPDATE store SET is_active=0 where store_id = your id here`;
```

Comment: Hi Marius; that query is very handy for store views; which tables should I use for deactivating stores and websites?

Comment: ...Or aren’t there any issues, if there are stores without default store views?

Comment: you cannot deactivate store groups and websites. I don't think there is a problem. The website will just simply not work if it does not have store groups or views. Which is what you want, I think

Comment: @Marius I have disabled the store but now I have to add redirection so that the customer should not open them manually. Do you have any idea about this?